# How to embed a live stream using the Youtube API on tvOS

Tags: youtube-api, tvos10

I need the ability to embed a Youtube live stream into a tvOS app. Due to the lack of an UIWebView, this was not possible with all previous tvOS. I hoped, that this feature will be included in the current tvOS 10 or Swift 3 release but it seems to me, that it is still missing.

Nevertheless, does anybody know a trick / something that I missed out during my journey  through the API documentation? I'm not allowed to use Youtube parsers like `pod 'youtube-parser'`, etc. I have to be in full compliance with the terms and conditions of Youtube.

Answer (score -1):

My solution so far is not good enough but it works fine
First, I find youtube playlist by using youtube-dl app
https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html
So, I can find link https://manifest.googlevideo.com/api/manifest/hls_playlist/*****.m3u8 in this format. Then, I just embedded this link to TVOS application.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Does this method fit in the Youtube TOS?

Comment: I'm not sure also. I'm finding better way too. However, to the best of my knowledge, embedded link from youtube cannot work with TVML.

Comment: The solutions I found right now are attached as followed.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32528624/how-to-play-youtube-content-on-tvos

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35608686/how-can-i-get-the-actual-video-url-of-a-youtube-live-stream

However, all of them violate TOS. In addition, tvOS cannot support webview, so that means video need to be converted to m3u8 or mp4 (or directly download video file as my method) before embedding to application.