# Get URL of video from YouTube API V3

Tags: android, youtube-api

How to get URL of YouTube video for streaming it in video view from new YouTube API V3.

Comment: can you post code or something more detailed ? The question you formulated is general and no precise.

Comment: link "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" isn't working anymore so how to get stream url using "https://youtube.googleapis.com/v3/"

Comment: You might be referring to HLS URL - [HTTP LIve Streaming protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) technology used by HTTP-based media streaming communications. There's a detailed instruction by @JAL on this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35608686/how-can-i-get-the-actual-video-url-of-a-youtube-live-stream) which might help you.