# Extract download link with title from youtube and download the file where title will be filename

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to extract download link from Youtube on last 5 days. But i couldn't figure it out how i will do that. I can extract download link that doesn't contain title. I'm just really curious on this.

**My current downloadable link generated from youtube is**

```
https://r2---sn-ax8xaj5ggpxg-q5je.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?mn=sn-ax8xaj5ggpxg-q5je&mm=31&id=o-ACiUieBRsJ--NcxCa2zCMTtnpMI8ZkRwTLmpHCweubMJ&ip=103.250.70.10&pl=24&mv=m&mt=1494041360&ms=au&ei=dkMNWd7cO4TwogOmqZWQCg&ipbits=0&initcwndbps=2500000&sparams=dur%2Cei%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&mime=video%2Fmp4&key=yt6&signature=C9FA79159588A31353C1371B51436FCA541A12B4.92A6D2677D783590172C450FF9414CE94FDE91E8&requiressl=yes&dur=306.108&source=youtube&lmt=1493728113446868&ratebypass=yes&expire=1494063063&upn=zW5TLf4jMEQ&itag=22
```

**How i can generate download link that contain title from youtube? maybe like this:**

```
http://r4---sn-4g5e6ney.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?dur=306.108&mm=31&source=youtube&mn=sn-4g5e6ney&ratebypass=yes&ipbits=0&mime=video%2Fmp4&ip=179.61.131.48&key=yt6&mt=1494038918&expire=1494060709&lmt=1493728113446868&itag=22&ei=RToNWcH5KYfYW_eAlZgO&id=o-AKoT7SFnd_dAgp_Bl-z6rF0dGUTagW48YwWJhn_3gUeD&ms=au&sparams=dur%2Cei%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&upn=fuRSNuDTrCs&pl=22&mv=u&signature=585E3440CE4432A81D490415975009B7047F80.40DE0A8919FA78EF130E17CD74BB96EC711BA570&title=Thodi+Der+-+Lyrical++-+Half+Girlfriend+-+Arjun+K+%26+Shraddha+K+-Farhan+Saeed+%26+Shreya+Ghoshal+-Kumaar
```

One more thing is i want that link to be downloaded when someone click on the generated link. I saw out there peoples are doing this how they are doing i don't know. If you then please help me in this case i just really need your help, Thank you.

Comment: No please edit this question. You didn't get it what i'm looking for it's not thumbnail.

Comment: Sorry... i added the wrong link... the possible duplicate is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35608686/how-can-i-get-the-actual-video-url-of-a-youtube-live-stream/35631022#35631022

Comment: @Chico3001 Edit this properly at top also.

Comment: I checked that URL you given me it's completely different.