# How to get download able url of live stream videos on youtube

Tags: javascript, java, c#, android, youtube

I'm writing a tool for downloading videos from youtube including live stream videos in c#.What I'm doing is: get html source from youtube url like "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bnpPLjEudoU" then I'll find a javascript fragment of code that contains the configurations for the playing video in JSON which contains a list of actual video url that I can be abale to download for 1080p-720p-480p-360p and so on,Its working perfectly with normal videos and some livestream videos but with Fox News Live chanel("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bnpPLjEudoU") I can't find any urls for 080p-720p-480p-360p other than a .m3u8 url

("https://manifest.googlevideo.com/api/manifest/hls_variant/keepalive/yes/id/bnpPLjEudoU.1~23716582/go/1/gcr/vn/sparams/ei,gcr,go,hfr,id,ip,ipbits,itag,maudio,playlist_type,ratebypass,requiressl,source,tx,txs,expire/requiressl/yes/itag/0/playlist_type/DVR/signature/3696DA0D44C88FCB370F27A780985017099507B2.9D3CB7209C75E0656424848394DAB3C65161365D/txs/9486106,9486107,9486108,9486113,9486114/maudio/1/expire/1514883856/ipbits/0/ratebypass/yes/dover/8/source/yt_live_broadcast/ip/118.107.71.247/key/yt6/ei/sPZKWu7RG4qx4AKKwJmACg/tx/9486113/hfr/1/file/index.m3u8"),

I've tried that .m3u8 url with VLC media player but there was only one image display on screen. So anyone please tell me is my solution to get videos from youtube ok? is there a better way? I'm writing the tool in c# but I can switch to any other programming languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Finally I found a solution myself,with normal video on youtube:
 +I get HTMLpage source  from a youtube url using:

```
    string pageSource = WebClient.DownloadString(youtubeURL)
```

+From HTML source I find the configurations for the video I want to download using Regularexpression and convert what I found to JSON:

```
    var dataRegex = new Regex(@"ytplayer\.config\s*=\s*(\{.+?\});", RegexOptions.Multiline);
        string extractedJson = dataRegex.Match(pageSource).Result("$1");
        Object[] objs = new Object[] { url, JObject.Parse(extractedJson) };
```

+Json object that I got will has the format like this:

{

"attrs": {

```
"id": "movie_player"
```

},

"params": {

```
"allowscriptaccess": "always",
"allowfullscreen": "true",
"bgcolor": "#000000"
```

},

"args": {

```
"c": "WEB",
"vmap": "",
"iv_load_policy": "1",
"innertube_api_version": "v1",
"xhr_apiary_host": "youtubei.youtube.com",
"length_seconds": "3826",
"relative_loudness": "-8.05900001526",
"pltype": "contentugc",
"title": "",
"host_language": "vi",
"enablecsi": "1",
"vm": "CAEQARgE",
"eventid": "gN9VWsD2HYu1qQHYh6DYCQ",
"plid": "AAViaNGgboLtCsQo",
"watermark": "",
"enablejsapi": "1",
"no_get_video_log": "1",
"loaderUrl": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oGeAFd9zjDI",
"vss_host": "s.youtube.com",
"oid": "h6xIstk06YQWVvfO-FkUjg",
"cver": "1.20180108",
"ldpj": "-35",
"timestamp": "1515577216",
"thumbnail_url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/oGeAFd9zjDI/default.jpg",
"view_count": "941366",
"idpj": "-9",
"fexp":"",
"loudness": "-29.0590000153",
"allow_ratings": "1",
"pyv_ad_channel": "",
"apiary_host": "",
"tmi": "1",
"fmt_list": "22/1280x720,43/640x360,18/640x360,36/320x180,17/176x144",
"video_id": "oGeAFd9zjDI",
"subtitles_xlb": "https://s.ytimg.com/yts/xlbbin/subtitles-strings-vi_VN-vfl-WQ1GC.xlb",
"videostats_playback_base_url": " ",
"player_response": "{}",
"ptk": "youtube_single",
"ucid": "UCIt0gjo6BZk37cLWm04LmCQ",
"apiary_host_firstparty": "",
"t": "1",
"swf_player_response": "1",
"ssl": "1",
"avg_rating": "4.11271858215",
"allow_embed": "1",
"is_listed": "1",
"cr": "VN",
"itct": "CAMQu2kiEwjAtvmMjc3YAhWLWioKHdgDCJso-B0=",
 "atc":"",
 "fflags":"",
"cl": "181278566",
"iv_invideo_url": "",
"player_error_log_fraction": "1.0",
"of": "Ds_CbA89Q3Fyo-EOejl1bA",
"token": "1",
"external_play_video": "1",
"show_pyv_in_related": false,
"account_playback_token": "",
"innertube_api_key": "AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8",
"csi_page_type": "watch,watch7_html5",
"adaptive_fmts": "",
"gapi_hint_params": "",
"author": "Mr Dolphin",
"ppv_remarketing_url": "",
"innertube_context_client_version": "1.20180108",
"hl": "vi_VN",
"url_encoded_fmt_stream_map": "list of actual urls for 1080p,720p,360p and so on, that will be able to download after decode",
"iv3_module": "1",
"keywords": " ",
"ismb": "8340000",
"watch_xlb": "https://s.ytimg.com/yts/xlbbin/watch-strings-vi_VN-vflzKZ5ht.xlb"
```

},

"url": "",

"min_version": "8.0.0",

"sts": 17536,

"assets": {

```
"js": "/yts/jsbin/player-vfluepRD8/vi_VN/base.js",
"css": "/yts/cssbin/player-vfl_z2Ycb/www-player.css"
```

},
  "html5": true
}

+Now when I have JsonObject I will find all the urls that can be able to download the video using:

```
     string urlsToDownload = json["args"]["url_encoded_fmt_stream_map"].ToString();
```

*With Live stream video I go through the same process as normal video but in last step instead of get a list of download able urls I have to get the .m3u8 url by:

```
   string downloadUrl = WebUtility.UrlDecode(json["args"]["hlsvp"].ToString());
```

+When I have .m3u8 url I download the livestream video using "FFMPEG"

Comment: The url get from "hlsvp" and [youtube-dl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35631022/1099884) are different. "hlsvp" method is quite easy but is it just return the lowest quality of the stream?