# How to get YouTube video URL from channel Id

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I want get video URL of my live channel

I know https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=UChF0CL3nPrnp7q3hfbvVg6A is permanent video URL but i need

URL like https://youtu.be/xxxfd or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxdfd

Is there any API to get it programmatically

Comment: One way that you can use is the following method [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35614542).

Answer (score 1):

1)Use the youtube site to find the video you want.

2)Click the 'Share' button below the video.

3)Click the 'Embed' button next to the link they show you.

4)Copy the iframe code given and paste it into the html of your web page.

Comment: My question was incorrect, I've updated it. I mean can we get it via API or programmatic way